# Needing help with Shoelace font

Tags: adobe-photoshop, font-design, illustrator-effects

Im trying to create a z and an i in this style of font I've never used a graphic design  type software and kinda just winging it at this stage so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. [image: shoelace font]

Comment: Hi shoozil, welcome to the site. Nice work so far! Could you [edit] your question to show us your attempts at creating the glyphs and explain where you're getting stuck?